# Can ghost sound be used to bypass arcane spell failure for verbal components?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

My level 6 magus has just been magically transformed, his mouth and tongue becoming weird. This causes a 15% arcane spell failure chance, and, when combined with the 10% from my armor, is a dangerously high 25%. (The kensai archetype removes the standard magus's ability to cast in armor without penalty.)

One of my cantrips is *ghost sound*, which allows me to create the sound of people talking and stuff. Could I use a successfully cast *ghost sound* spell to cast other spells with vocal components to avoid the 15% arcane spell failure for having Cthulhu-mouth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The spell [*ghost sound*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghost-sound) is of no help here

The description of [verbal components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components) says

> A verbal component is a spoken incantation. **To provide a verbal component, you must be able to speak in a strong voice.** A *silence* spell or a gag spoils the incantation (and thus the spell). a spellcaster who has been deafened has a 20% chance of spoiling any spell with a verbal component that he tries to cast.

While the spell [*ghost sound*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghost-sound) can create an audible *illusion* of a creature casting a spell, this illusion is no substitute for *you* speaking in a strong voice.

I urge you to find soon someone capable of reversing this transformation your character's undergone unless there's an especially desirable upshot to it. Or, if the transformation's permanent, consider the feat [Silent Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/silent-spell-metamagic---final) and, if you insist on armor, [Still Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/still-spell-metamagic---final), too.

Comment: Its a one (maybe two) level game. We might be able to under the curse(s) affecting the party but we currently do not know. All we know is that when we use detect magic we go blind until we stop using it. The curse keeps worsening as well.
I didnt think the spell would help but it was worth a shot.

Comment: I vaguely remember there being a clause in *ghost sound* that specified it couldn't produce intelligible speech. I'm surprised you didn't quote that here... Or was that only in 3.5rd edition?

Comment: @GMJoe Both are pretty clear about being able to create "talking, singing, [and] shouting [that can] be virtually any type of sound within the volume limit." Although I think *audible glamer* might've been more limited in *2E* and earlier.